# How to persist the value of a dropdown menu in a React/Redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm building a single page filter site and am trying to figure out how to keep the dropdown menu selections a user has made persistent through a page refresh, but I'm not even sure where to begin. Each dropdown is a filter and lives in its own stateless component.  All my state management is being done through Redux.

Comment: [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want to keep the selections user has made, you need to update your url with current selections. Example:

> www.example.com/some-path?**first_selection=yogurt**

Else you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Read about it. But I wouldn't recommend if the user would have the privilege to share the url.

```
// setter
localStorage.setItem('myData', data);

// getter
localStorage.getItem('myData');
```